# Appcelerator iOS Module with OpenCV - OpenCV's camera won't open

Tags: objective-c, opencv, appcelerator

So, I am developing an `Appcelerator iOS Module which uses OpenCV` to do some image processing with the camera.

The thing is, the camera won't open at all. I read the official [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/dc8/tutorial_video_processing.html) example, followed the steps (of course, had to adapt things to be used as an Appc Module), also followed the [iOSModuleQuickStart](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Quick+Start) from the Appcelerator Wiki. I thought I did it right, except that it just doesn't work.

This is my `.h` View class from the Module:

```
#import "TiUIView.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

using namespace cv;

@interface ComIosopencvmoduleTestView : TiUIView<CvPhotoCameraDelegate> 
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
    CvPhotoCamera *photoCamera;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CvPhotoCamera* photoCamera;

@end
```

This is the implementation of it (.mm):

```
#import "ComIosopencvmoduleTestView.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"
// some other imports....

@implementation ComIosopencvmoduleTestView

@synthesize photoCamera;

#pragma mark - UI Actions

- (void)initializeState
{
    self.photoCamera = [[CvPhotoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.photoCamera.delegate = self;
    self.photoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    self.photoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
    self.photoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
    self.photoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    [self.photoCamera start];
    // The instantiation and the call to start method, should do the trick, but it doesn't
}

@end
```

And, this is how I call it on `JS`, from Appcelerator Studio:

```
var VWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
var VView = VItire.createView({});

var VItire = require('com.iosopencvmodule.test');

VWindow.add(VView); 
VWindow.open();
```

This code, according to what I understood from both Tutorials, OpenCV and Appcelerator, should be enough to open the Camera as the App is launched.

Please, what could possibly be wrong? I am going mad with this. Thanks in advance!

Please help!

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: Hey man. Yes it is. The thing will not open at all.